# Raising volume of one mic in an audio track to meet others' mics volumes

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve

I have a long video where I and other people talk. Whereas the voices of others sound good, my mic captured mine with a very low volume. The problem is that the video is long and voices alternate, so I cannot go looking for every piece of audio where I talk and raising the volume one by one.

[image: volumes]

Is there a way to automatically raise my voice while keeping others' voices in a good level as they currently are?

I think I have to use some "compression" and "normalization" but I don't really know how they work, so if you provide specific steps it will be highly appreciated. I already played with normalization without much success. I attempted to increase the volume of the whole piece, so my voice reaches a good volume, and then "normalise" the volume to see if that will lower the voices of others to their initial state, but it didn't work (I probably did something wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For it to sound good, you would certainly have to raise and lower the volume by hand using keyframes. If you want a quick and dirty solution, you can use a limiter or compressor. A limiter sets a ceiling of volume that cannot be surpassed. This way, you can turn up the volume significantly, which would make your voice touch this ceiling while others would be crashing through that ceiling. The limiter than lowers the volume of the parts that would crash through the ceiling, effectively putting loud and quiet parts closer together in volume.

However, you will also hear an extreme limiter / compression like this. Quiet sounds when nobody talks will be awkwardly loud, breaths sound like from an asmr video and you will most likely have a problem with background noise, which will be more audible aswell.

To avoid this problem in the first place, I would recommend you use microphones for each person that's speaking, so you can adjust the volume easily in post-production.

Comment: Do you have any advise about what parameters to use in the "Limiter" and "Multiband Compressor" in Resolve?

Comment: I have no idea about how to use the compressor... I did a small "patch" by raising the `Volume` and using the `Limiter` and there are some negative side effects but at least my voice can be heard. I will accept the answer, but if you are able to give advise on compressor parameters, I'll appreciate if you complete your answer with such details

Comment: @user1156544 Are you on a Mac or PC? (I ask because on the Mac, the AUDynamicsProcessor might more clearly show you what's happening than a multi-band compressor.)

Comment: I am on a PC...